# Two formulas in one line

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

I need to put two formulas in the same line as in the picture. Notice that some formulas in the left side are formulas with several terms (for example the second one has 6 terms). Could you help me, please?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the code for these equations?

Comment: @Roland thanks by your attention is unnecessary to use the same terms, you can use for example the term $a_i$ for all terms. My question is more related in how to split the area, using this big formula? Also, the right side equations (for example) $k=1,i>0$ need to appear aligned to the right side. And the left side equations aligned to the left side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution, which uses an `flalign` environment as well as an `aligned` environment in the second equation, ...

- ... aligns the left-side equations on the far left,
- ... aligns the `k=1,i>0`-type conditions on the far right, and
- ... provides vertical centering of the two-line fragment to the right of the `=` symbol in the middle row relative to (a) the `=` symbol to the left and the `k=3,i>1` term and the equation number on the far right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\providecommand\mL{\mathcal{L}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{18} % just for this example

\begin{flalign}
 x\oplus x &= \mL\oplus\mL\oplus x\oplus x &k=1,i>0 \\
 x\oplus x &= 
    \begin{aligned}
       &\mL\oplus\mL\oplus\mL\oplus {} \\
       &\quad x\oplus x\oplus x
    \end{aligned} & k=3,i>1 \\
 x\oplus x &= \mL\oplus\mL\oplus\mL\oplus x\oplus x& k=2
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, just for me it is new "\providecommand". Why do use this? My best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano - `\providecommand` is just like `\newcommand` except that it doesn't create the new command (here: `\mL`) if a command with that name already exists. (In such a circumstance, `\newcommand` would throw an error.) There was no particularly good reason for using `\providecommand` instead of `\newcommand` here. Just me being needlessly fancy, I suppose. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your squisite kindness.

Comment: Hi, :-) I just now read your message casually. I hadn't received the notification with the red number 1. Excuse me very much and I have understood the meaning of your comment.